# OpenAM - Configure Form Based and Basic authentication together for an app

Tags: authentication, spring-security, forms-authentication, basic-authentication, openam

We have an old monolithic web app, which has two entry points, one accessed via regular form based authentication, and the other via basic authentication. We've been testing OpenAM as an SSO solution.

- Just form based authentication works great.
- Just BASIC authentication works great

How do we get Form & Basic working hand in hand on the same application ?

Few points about the setup;

- We are using J2EE web agent
- Agent is configured to point to a realm for authentication.
- Form based auth is going against this realm.
- Form & Basic using the same datastore for auth, and work on the same realm

We want http://www.example.com to be authenticated via form & http://www.example.com/xyz to be authenticated against Basic.

We have done that using spring security & filter-intercept in the past. So not looking to get it done at the app level, but at the OpenAM server/agent level.

Comment: Why do you care at all if HTTP basic auth or form-based auth is used? Do you consider one of the two authentication methods more secure than the other?

Comment: Not a security stand point, one is a REST API entry point, and one is the application entry point. There are different users types accessing the system.

Comment: When you use an Agent (URL Policy/J2EE) it will always return a '403' to the caller when the request does not offer the SSO tracking cookie. Authentication does not happen at the agent but at OpenAM. The agent is a policy enforcement point.  In case of the REST call the client would have to follow the redirect and insert the retrieved SSO token into the request. Do you really want to go this route?